How can I start the Claude AI Android app from another Android app?
How can I start the Claude AI Android app from another Android app?
What is the package name?
I can start it then via:
Intent launchIntent = MainActivity.mainActivity.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("x.y.z");
if (launchIntent != null) {
    startActivity(launchIntent);
} 

Can I pass a prompt?

"What is the package name?" -- package names are visible in the URL of the Play Store page for the app. "Can I pass a prompt?" -- you would need to see if they have a documented API.

Thank you. The url helped me. Can you move the text to an answer and I will mark my question as solved +1.


What is the package name?

One way to find the application ID is to find the app on the Play Store. Google uses the application ID in the URL.
So, if by "Claude AI", you mean Claude by Anthropic, the Play Store URL is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anthropic.claude, and the application ID is com.anthropic.claude.
Depending on your device, you might also get the package name from the Settings app, if you go to that app's screen within Settings.

Can I pass a prompt?

In some quick searching, I do not see where Anthropic has published an Intent-based API for their app. They might have one, but it might require more research or experimentation.
